# Practical uses of fuzzy theory?

Tags: fuzzy-logic

from your experience/from what you have encountered, what are some practical applications of fuzzy systems? I know about system control and fuzzy controllers, about intrinsic linguistic support, but here I refer to concrete applications of fuzzy, where this approach was proven to be successful or fitted very well.

Answer (score 4):

We have implemented a robotic path planner using a fuzzy controller. Traditionally, controllers are implemented using PID Controllers and are a real pain to calibrate. A fuzzy controller is more intuitive to program, since it uses a mapping table that explores the human knowledge.

For example, this could be a fuzzy rule in a fuzzy controller:

```
IF distance from car in front of you IS small AND speed IS very fast 
  THEN brake pressure IS very high.
```

Traditional fuzzy logic (fuzzy sets, etc) are employed to define the ranges for things like "very fast" and "small" and the corresponding operations (AND, OR, etc).

From my experience, 90% of time a traditional and proven PID controller will be enough, simple and reliable.

Answer (score 3):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_logic#Application_areas):

> Fuzzy logic is used in the operation or programming of:

```
* Air conditioners
* Automobile and such vehicle subsystems as automatic transmissions, ABS and cruise control
* Tokyo monorail
* Cameras
* Digital image processing, such as edge detection
* Dishwashers
* Elevators
* Some microcontrollers and microprocessors (e.g. Freescale 68HC12)
* Hydrometeor classification algorithms for polarimetric weather radar
* Language filters on message boards and chat rooms for filtering out offensive text
* The Massive engine used in the Lord of the Rings films, which allowed large-scale armies to enact random yet orderly movements
* Mineral Deposit estimation
* Pattern recognition in Remote Sensing
* Rice cookers
* Video game artificial intelligence
* Home appliances (e.g. washing machine)
```

Here's [another](http://www.dementia.org/~julied/logic/applications.html) detailed list of applications for fuzzy logic. And [some advocacy](http://www.aptronix.com/fide/whyfuzzy.htm) about how fuzzy logic is good for some applications.

Comment: Thank you. If one wants to add more, feel free to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Optical character reader softwares and handwritting recognition uses fuzzy logic.

Comment: I think that's a pretty generic comment. While fuzzy can certainly be applied to parts of a handwritting recognition software, not all OCR's use fuzzy logic.

Comment: I think the question doesnt say that list applications which ONLY use fuzzy logic.